# Multiple prototype cells in UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

So I am trying to set up my UITableViewController that has a headerview, footerview, and then multiple prototype cells in between them. When I go to run my code on my simulator, only the hearderview and footerview are displaying and the prototype cells are not. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class UploadTrackTableViewController: UITableViewController {





    var headerView: UploadHeader!
    var footerView: UploadFooter!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView as! UploadHeader
        footerView = tableView.tableFooterView as! UploadFooter

    }

}


extension UploadTrackTableViewController {


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 1 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 2 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 1
        }
       }

       override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "trackTitleCell", for: indexPath) as! TrackTitleTableViewCell


                     return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "genreCell", for: indexPath) as! SelectGenreTableViewCell

            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 2 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "featuredArtistCell", for: indexPath) as! AddFeaturedArtistTableViewCell

            return cell
        } else {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "audioCell", for: indexPath) as! SelectAudioFileTableViewCell

        return cell

        }
    }

}
```

And here is a screenshot of how my controller looks on interface builder. 
[image: Interface Builder]

And here is a screenshot of the simulator.
[image: Simulator]

Not sure if setting this up as a tableview is the best option maybe I should go for a scrollview with this UI but I am not sure what would work best.

here is what the view controller looks like now. [image: Updated Simulator]

Comment: Did you try to set height for your cells ?

Comment: if you print the cells after creation, does it give you some information?

Comment: I found what I did wrong, it was a simple mistake with adding the class the to the ViewController in storyboard, rookie mistake. Now I am having a problem with the cells not loading in the right size, please see updated question with screen shot. I'm not sure how to fix it to where the cells are loading with correct height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only 1 section and `UITableView` has delegate functions of

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return 'your custom view'
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return 'your custom view'
}
```

You can return you own custom view of header and footer here.

Happy coding. :)

Comment: I found what I did wrong, it was a simple mistake with adding the class the to the ViewController in storyboard, rookie mistake. Now I am having a problem with the cells not loading in the right size, please see updated question with screen shot. I'm not sure how to fix it to where the cells are loading with correct height